# Position labels when they are overlapping in a stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

I have been working in a couple of stacked bar plots, but some of bins are too small to fit the label, resulting in overlapping, unreadable labels. See the graph below:

[image]

Please consider the MWE below, which generated the above graph.

**Q: Is it possible to add lines from the labels  pointing to where the bars are? So that they are offset and more readable?**

```
 tribble(
~parm, ~value,
"b1", 0.009,
"g1", 0.664,
"b2", 0.000,
"ra", 0.000,
"rc", 0.000,
"ax", 0.084,
"cx", 0.086,
"ex", 0.179,
"ay", 0.045,
"cy", 0.043,
"ey", 0.102
) -> doc1


 
 
doc2 <- tribble(
  ~parm, ~value,
  "b1", 0.181,
  "g1", 0.289,
  "b2", 0.181,
  "ra", 0.000,
  "rc", 0.000,
  "ax", 0.001,
  "cx", 0.001,
  "ex", 0.002,
  "ay", 0.001,
  "cy", 0.001,
  "ey", 0.002,
  "re", 0.000,
  "rf", 0.000,
  "b3", 0.289
)


doc1 <- doc1 %>% mutate(model = "exp")
doc2 <- doc2 %>% mutate(model = "exp2")


finalpow <- doc1 %>% full_join(doc2)


# Make a stacked bar plot
ggplot(finalpow, aes(x = model, y = value, fill = parm)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(label = parm), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme_luis() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Parameter", y = "Variance explained in NCP", fill = "Parameter") +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: The ggrepel package does this well. When I'm making graphics for print and need to repel just some labels, I calculate a subset (maybe based on minimum bar size to be considered small), then place regular labels that _don't_ have that subset and repelled labels that _do_ have the subset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Camille already suggested in the comments, you can use the [`ggrepel`](https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html) with `geom_text_repel` function and replace it with `geom_text`. You can play with `max.overlaps` if you want. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
doc1 <- doc1 %>% mutate(model = "exp")
doc2 <- doc2 %>% mutate(model = "exp2")

finalpow <- doc1 %>% full_join(doc2)
#> Joining, by = c("parm", "value", "model")

# Make a stacked bar plot
ggplot(finalpow, aes(x = model, y = value, fill = parm)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = parm), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Parameter", y = "Variance explained in NCP", fill = "Parameter") +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Please check the link above for a lot of more great examples with this package.